# ApplicationIdleDetectionMode and DispatcherTimer

Tags: windows-phone-7, timer

I'm currently working on a problem which i'm not able to solve...

I have developed a WP7 app which sends periodical location updates to a service. Therefore I'm using a DispatcherTimer which works great. Now I also want to do this when the screen is locked. So I set ApplicationIdleDetectionMode to "Disabled" in App() just after InitializePhoneApplication().

Now I have a very strange behavior because the timer which is running as the screen gets locked seems to finish but I cannot start it again. timer.Start() gets called but the Tick-Event does not get called. When I unlock the screen at my device it is working again...

Anyone got an idea how to solve this?
Or maybe any other advice how I can achieve such a behavior?

Greetings
Dominik

Comment: Why do you need to stop the timer in the first place? Can’t you just keep the timer running? What is the interval on the timer? What is the “Screen time-out” value on the device under Settings > lock & wallpaper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m surprised that the framework itself would stop an active timer when the application is locked when `ApplicationIdleDetection` is disabled although it's a distinct possibility. In RunKeeper we don’t use a `DispatcherTimer` to do that anyway, we keep track of the user’s time on an activity by using `Observable.Timer`.

One thing I was going to suggest anyway was that sending position data every time interval might not be the most efficient anyway. If you set a movement threshold on the location service then you will only get a position when the user’s position has changed by that amount, you could then send the position data every time the location has changed. To preserve battery power while the device is locked, you could store the positions, and then send them when the application is reactivated.

Comment: DispatcherTimer seems to be the problem...
I have tested to use the normal System.Threading.Timer and its working. No idea whats the difference between them and why I have decided to use DispatcherTimer but it the problem seems to be solved.

Cause of your advice with the battery runtime:
The GeoWatcher is not running all the time. I just use TryStart and stop the watcher afterwards. So this should not be such a batterie problem. But for sure I will have to test this.

Than you for your help!